# What is the difference and preferred way between jsonEncode() and json.encode() in Dart?

Tags: dart, flutter, angular-dart

In Flutter doc, it uses `jsonEncode()`, while in Angular doc, it uses `json.encode()`. What is the difference and preferred way between the two?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`jsonEncode` as alias for `json` was introduced because `json` often collided with a varible name `json` many used for the variable that holds the JSON value.

```
var json = http.get(...);
var data = json.decode(json); // error
var data = jsonDecode(json); // ok
```

Comment: oh, I finally get it why there is jsonEncode then. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference.  From the the [`dart:convert` docs for `jsonEncode`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.1/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html):

> Shorthand for `json.encode`.

Comment: Cool. Thanks a lot for the quick answer. I checked the doc before, but didn't realize the "shorthand" words. Due to time limitation, I can only accept the answer after 9 minutes.

Comment: I was about to mark your post as the answer, but after seeing Günter Zöchbauer's answer, I think that clarifies why dart introduces a new shorthand at the first place. Sorry that I will mark his post as the answer since that is more clear to me. And I have upvoted your answer and Thank you very much for your quick reply, detail answer and well structured content.

Comment: @sgon00 No worries!  I'm glad I got to learn something too. =)

Answer (score 1):

In the upcoming [Sound Null-Safety update](https://dart.dev/null-safety), currently in beta, the alias `jsonEncode` does not work, so just use `json.encode`